Zoomed images don't have different sizes according to JavaScript
Is there any way to get the actual size of a zoomed image via javascript?  After adding a css zoom affect to the image and then getting the size via JS it returns the original size.


var img = document.getElementById('img');
var box = document.getElementById('box')

box.innerHTML += "<br />height: " 
    + img.height +
    "px<br />width: "
    + img.width + "px";
#img{zoom:20%}
<div id="box">
  <img id="img" src="https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th/id/OIP.Lt_KplHna5Rxc5JdcOAXuQHaHa?rs=1&pid=ImgDetMain" />
</div>



https://codepen.io/tinkersncody/pen/dyxENwq

Please, post a [mre] here, not on an external unreliable (not to criticize codepen, maybe it is very reliable and will last a thousand years. But we have no control on that), probably ephemere, site. Plus, SO already have the equivalent with snippets.

That's because they don't: the image doesn't change dimensions, only the  image element does, so check the element's dimensions using the function mentioned by Timur.

(And on a modern webdev note: don't use + for strings, don't use <br>, and don't set innerHTML unless you really need to set HTML code. Put a span in that div, and set its .textContent using template string syntax. E.g. const span = box.querySelector(`span`); span.textContent =`height: ${...}, width: ${...}`;)

You can use the getBoundingClientRect() method:


var img = document.getElementById('img');
var box = document.getElementById('box')

img.onload = () => {
  box.innerHTML += "<br />height: " 
    + img.getBoundingClientRect().height
    + "px<br />width: "
    + img.getBoundingClientRect().width
    + "px";
}
#img{zoom:20%}
<div id="box">
  <img id="img" src="https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th/id/OIP.Lt_KplHna5Rxc5JdcOAXuQHaHa?rs=1&pid=ImgDetMain" />
</div>



img.onload = () => {...} is added to make sure image is loaded before getting the values.

But if we're fixing this, probably a good idea to fix that string concatenation too. (const { width, height } = img.getBoundingClientRect(); and then use normal templating string syntax without the <br> elements. It's not the HTML 4.01 era anymore, after all)
